# How to access nested java member variable value using string with dot operator

Tags: java, json, reflection

If we have class like

```
class A{
    private B b;

    //getter & setter
}

class B{
    private C c;
    //getter and setter
}

class C{
    private String d="hello";
    private Map<String,String> e = new HashMap<>();
//getter and setter
}
```

if we want to write a function like below do we have any readily available framework?

```
public void test( A a){
    String result = getValue(a, "b.c.d");//result should be equal to "hello"
}
```

To make complicated the framework should also be able to handle fetch like:

```
String result = getValue(a, "b.c.e.f");//result should be able to fetch value from Map 'e' for key 'f'
```

I know if we can serialize A to JSON then I think we have some readily available API, but is there any way without serializing to JSON, we can still use reflection to do this lookup?

Comment: *"do we have any readily available framework?"* [**Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: But, you could try a scripting library.

Comment: @Andreas which one?

Comment: See first comment. There are many to choose from, and most of them likely supports the `.` syntax, so do your own research in to Java scripting libraries, and choose the one that works best for you. Likely is small one that supports `.` syntax.